# Как отключить POI на Яндекс Карте?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

У нас Яндекс Карта встроена в корпоративный продукт, и там все эти магазины только мешают. Как отключить POI совсем или управлять уровнем детализации по аналогии с Google Maps ?

Answer (score 0):

Убрать сами POI с подложки карт не получится.
Но можно сделать их некликабельными через опцию [yandexMapDisablePoiInteractivity](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/Map.html#Map__param-options.yandexMapDisablePoiInteractivity)

Answer (score 0):

Да, сейчас JS API Яндекс Карт ещё не перенесли на векторные карты, потому нынешние POI-объекты являются частью предварительно отрисованной подложки, и их можно только [сделать некликабельными](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/Map.html#Map__param-options.yandexMapDisablePoiInteractivity). Вероятно стоит дождаться неизбежного (как мне кажется) перехода API на 3D.

Если же речь о мобильном приложении, то там основа уже векторная, потому технических препятствий быть не должно. Тут вопрос лишь в коммерческой целесообразности для геосервисов Яндекса.

Потому для MapKit о возможности отключить POI стоит спросить у поддержки. Быть может для крупных коммерческих заказчиков Яндекс может дать возможность выключать коммерческие POI.